# How to copy value from one collection to another with some conditions

Tags: performance, mongodb, copy

I have two collections, for example pupils and schools.

Pupil:

```
{
     Id,
     SchoolId,
     Name,
     interests
}
```

School

```
{
     Id,
     Name,
     interests
}
```

Pupil and school have relations (SchoolId is a foreign key in term of rdbms). At begin pupils haven't any interests. I want to copy interests from school to pupil and do it very fast.
Solution with loop looks very slow. May be there are any alternative ways?

Answer (score 0):

Mongo does not allow operations across multiple collections.

But why would a loop be slow? You just iterate over all documents in the `School` collection and initialize all documents in the `Pupils` collection with non-existent or empty `interests` array with the value of the school.

You just need one update for every school.